# How to add content in custom menu block?

Tags: routes, nodes

I have own menu type "Footer menu". When I add new content, "Footer menu" is not display in Menu setings. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's in the Content Type's settings screen under "Menu settings", you have to tick the Footer Menu to make it available for selection.

Comment: thx, it`s work!

Comment: is possible to add one content type to more menu blocks?